# React hook setState, setTimeout memory leak

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, react-hooks, settimeout, use-effect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import styles from './TextAnimation.module.scss';

const TextAnimation = () => {
    const [typedText, setTypedText] = useState([
        "Welcome to Byc",
        "Change your Life"
    ]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState();
    const [inType, setInType] = useState(false);
    
    
    
    let attachClasses = [styles.Blink];
    if(inType) {
        attachClasses.push(styles.Typing)
    }
        
    const typingDelay = 200;
    const erasingDelay = 100;
    const newTextDelay = 5000;
    
    let textArrayIndex = 0;
    let charIndex = 0;
    
    const type = () => {
        if(charIndex < typedText[textArrayIndex].length + 1) {
            setValue(typedText[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex));
            charIndex ++;
            setTime();
        } else {
            setInType(false);
            setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
        }
    };
    
    const setTime = () => {
        setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
    };
    
    const erase = () => {
        if(charIndex > 0) {
            setValue(typedText[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1));
            charIndex --;
            setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
        } else {
            setInType(false);
            textArrayIndex ++;
            if(textArrayIndex >= typedText.length) {
                textArrayIndex = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(type, newTextDelay - 3100);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        type();
    }, [])
    
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.TextAnimation}>
            <span className={styles.Text} >{value}</span><span className={attachClasses.join(' ')} >&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TextAnimation;
```

I'am trying to make text animation, but i got an message just like this...

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear timeouts when your component unmounts, otherwise maybe a timeout will run after the component is unmounted.

To do that :

- store the return value of each timeout in a list in some ref (with `React.useRef` for example)
- return a callback in `useEffect` that clears the timeouts with `clearTimeout(<return value of setTimeout>)`